# Searching for values that contain "<" and ">" in a list in Python

Tags: python

Educational question:

In this code it gives me the amount of values that are written like `"<something>"` (it's about the "<" and ">").

```
tokens = ['<greeting>', 'Hello World!', '</greeting>']

count = 0
for token in tokens:
    if token[0] == '<' and token[-1] == '>':
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Can someone explain me the `if token[0] == '<' and token[-1] == '>'` part?

Because how I am reading this is: if the first value in list tokens (which is `"<greetings>"`) is equal to '<' and if the last value (which is `'</greetings>'`) is equal to '>' then add 1 to count.

I would write it like  `if token == '<' and token == '>'` but that is not correct.

Thanks!

Comment: token[0] is `'<'` and not `'<greeting>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `token` is an element in the `tokens` list
2. The condition checks if the first `char` of the element is `<` and the last char being `>`
3. The `count` variable is incremented each time the signs are found, i.e. 2 in this case (`<greeting>` and `</greeting>`)

Comment: @number42 you're welcome, you may accept the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically iterating over the list of tokens and the checking if the first character of token starts with `'<'` and ends with `'>'`. You can compress your logic in single statement

```
sum(1 for token in tokens if token[0] == '<' and token[-1] == '>')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code iterates over the list in `for token in tokens:` so for the fist iteration you have `'<greeting>'` in the token variable.

Because it's a string `token[0]` is '<' and `token[-1]` is '>'.

`token[-1]` is the same thing with `token[len(token)-1]`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `token` contains only one string from your list, and `token[0]` is the first char of that string.

By adding print statements you can see for yourself:

```
tokens = ['<greeting>', 'Hello World!', '</greeting>']

count = 0
for token in tokens:
    print()
    print('token', token)
    print(token[0])
    print(token[-1])
    if token[0] == '<' and token[-1] == '>':
        count += 1

print('count', count)
```

This prints:

```
token <greeting>
<
>

token Hello World!
H
!

token </greeting>
<
>
count 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two Python language features you have to understand in this code snippet to get the idea behind it:

1. `for token in tokens` part iterates over the list of tokens and pulls the next token every iteration. First it will get the `'<greeting>'`, then `'Hello World!'` and last `'</greeting>'`.
2. `if token[0] == '<' and token[-1] == '>'` part is responsible for recognizing the `"<something>"` format with a usage of indexing. `[0]` indexing refers to the first character of the token and `[-1]` indexing refers to the last character. This behaviour is a neat feature of Python to "count" the iterables "the other way".